# Template.autorun() and Tracker.afterFlush() not working

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, autorun

From what I could understand from the official docs, function passed as parameter to `template.autorun` should run whenever there is an update in the `DOM`.

But I don't find it happening.

```
//dummies.html
<template name="dummies" >
    {{#each dummies}}
        {{this.count}}&nbsp;
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

---

```
//dummies.js
Template.dummies.onRendered(function(){
    var counter = 0;
    setInterval(function(){
        Dummies.insert({count: counter++})
    }, 2000);
    this.autorun(function(){
        console.log("From autorun:", Dummies.find().count()) //--->Line1
        Tracker.afterFlush(function(){
            console.log("From afterFlush:", Dummies.find().count())  //--->Line2
        });
    });
});

Template.dummies.helpers({
    dummies: function(){
        return Dummies.find();
    }
});
```

Both `Line1` and `Line2` are being executed just once. Shouldn't they be executed everytime `Dummies.insert()` is called?

I mean, shouldn't they be called whenever template is updated?

If I have misunderstood the docs, Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

The code you show looks good. And yes, the code inside autorun is rerun each time a reactive source is changed. Because the Dummies collection is a reactive source this should trigger a rerun on each insert in the collection.

I copied your code into a small project and it works as expected. Every 2 seconds, a new record with incremented count is created and both Line 1 and Line 2 are show in the console. And the new count is displayed in in the template.

Can you show how you have setup your publish and subscribe? Or are you using autopublish?

Comment: Thanks for your interest ... I too suspected this ... Then I installed back `insecure` and `autopublish` to find out if it is a problem with the publications and subscriptions ... But result is same

Comment: Do you get new records in MongoDB every 2 seconds? And is the content in your browser updated with counts displaying from the template?

Comment: If I increase the `timeout` from `2000` to `3000`, `console.log` works sometimes and sometimes doesn't .... More the delay, more the probability of getting the result .... does autorun actually require a delay to work smoothly ....????

Comment: I feel this is happening because my application has become large. When I created another project with only this code, It works smoothly ....